# Perfmon.exe not showing values for Network Interface via powershell

Tags: powershell, collections, perfmon

I've been trying to make powershell make a csv file with certain information in Windows 7's perfmon.exe

Most of it works, but it seems to ignore 3 counters.

The script looks like the following:

```
$SampleInterval="4"
$MaxSamples="15"
$FileDestinationFolder="C:\Perfmon"
$date = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()
Get-Counter 
$gc = ('\Network Interface(`*)\Current Bandwith', 
        '\Network Interface(`*)\Packets Recieved/sec',
        '\Network Interface(`*)\Packets Sent/sec',
        '\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Write Bytes/sec',
        '\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Read Bytes/sec',
        '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time',
        '\Processor(_Total)\% Idle Time',
        '\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use',  
        '\Memory\Available MBytes')
Get-Counter -counter $gc -SampleInterval $SampleInterval -MaxSamples $MaxSamples | export-counter -force -path ("$FileDestinationFolder\PerfMon-$date.csv") -FileFormat csv
```

I do get stats for PhysicalDisk, Processor and Memory, but none of the Network Interfaces. The path for Network Interface is fetched from the Data Collector itself. 
Any clue why this may be so?

EDIT --
If I read them in alone, I can see that it prints all the network interfaces in the Powershell ISE, but doesn't write the content to the csv file.

Example on output is

> Timestamp                 CounterSamples
>   ---------                 --------------
>   06-12-2012 15:13:30       \dkspare03\network interface(intel[r] 82577lm gigabi
>                             t network connection)\bytes total/sec :
>                             27101,2080498825

```
                      \\dkspare03\network interface(intel[r] centrino[r] ad
                      vanced-n 6200 agn)\bytes total/sec :                 
                      0
```

Currently, Network Interface has an escape character where it tells what NIC to read.
In case I do not have it, powershell enlist an error as following:

> Get-Counter : Internal performance counter API call failed. Error: c0000bb9.
>   At line:38 char:12
>   + Get-Counter <<<<  -counter $gc -SampleInterval $SampleInterval -MaxSamples $M
>   axSamples | export-counter -force -path ("$FileDestinationFolder\PerfMon-$date.
>   csv") -FileFormat csv
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Ge 
>      tCounterCommand

Comment: On a windows7 your code works, I've just changed `$date = Get-Date -f 'ddMMYYYY' to avoid error in file creation.

Comment: Are you able to see the Network information in a csv file? What I think is happening, is that if I include all (using * as a wildcard), it can't write multiple lines into one field. Thus I got no idea on how it should work if I don't name every single card by itself. The problem is that this script is to be distributed to several servers that doesn't contain the same hardware. If it works for you, can you post a picture of it or alike? Personally I run windows 7 as well. The problems also exist on 2K8R2 machines.

Comment: works on Windows 7 with PowerShell 3 installed

Comment: Oh! I should have mentioned that I'm using 2.0. I will immediately update it.

Comment: Everything works, if I don't use the wildcard on Network Interface, but declare the specific interface instead, or just neglect that part and don't try to print it out to the csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counter seemed to require Powershell 3.0. The date variable was edited to avoid creating further troubles in naming files and folders.
Furthermore, "Recieved" had to be changed to "Received".